# "Regarding" vs. "For" in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-difference

Consider these two sentences I wrote:

> 1. Relaxation is an issue for interfacial systems in general, especially when there is an IL on one side of the interface.
> 2. Regarding the interfacial systems, relaxation is an issue in general, especially when there is an IL on one side of the interface.

The sentence is going to be the opening sentence of a paragraph. So, I changed the sentence 1 to sentence 2 to have more focus on the topic of the paragraph. Are these two sentence equivalent? Which is more idiomatic? which one is preferred in the situation I mentioned?

In fact, I still have a problem using "Regarding something", I feel it's not as idiomatic as I think! If "Regarding X" is not a good choice to shift focus on X, I would like to know which other structures are used.

Comment: The first sentence sounds more natural. The second is awkward and difficult to parse.

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks, what about rephrasing it for more focus on the "interfacial systems"?

Comment: Given only the one sentence, relaxation *is* the focus—so it makes sense that it comes first. (It discusses relaxation specifically and does so in the context of interfacial systems.) Changing the word order wouldn't make sense—unless you didn't mention relaxation at all.

Comment: Are "interfacial systems" *interfaces*?

Comment: Perhaps you mean interface system? Rather than interfacial.

Comment: I suppose "interfacial systems" to be systems which rely on interfaces.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It can be a term in chemistry, example: https://www.crcpress.com/Liquid-Interfacial-Systems-Oscillations-and-Instability/Birikh-Briskman-Velarde-Legros/p/book/9780824742959

Answer (score 1):

> With interfacial systems the issue of relaxation (often) arises, especially when
>   there is an IL on one side of the interface.

The definite article is not idiomatic in your #2. You're speaking of interfacial systems in general, and for that purpose, use the plural here.

Use the simple present (**arises**) to indicate that this is a regular or normal occurrence, SOP, and then you can dispense with "in general".  It the issue does not always arise, you can say "often".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term is **interface**, and not interfacial.

For example:

We describe the design of the RELAX system for **programming interface relaxation techniques** for partial differential equations (PDEs). The PDEs are solved over composite domains. [bolding is mine]

[interface and relaxation](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/RELAX-%3A-A-Software-Platform-for-PDE-Interface-McFaddin-Rice/bc14f98b6bd349b7f6d1fbe6d2c8f00698d0eed3)

I recommend: In general, relaxation is an issue in interfacing or interface systems etc.

Two systems can interface: they are interfacing systems. That is also a possibility here. Interfacial is a  no-go.

Comment: It's jargon: https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.92.042128

Comment: Only for liquids and it would be interfacial tension: https://petrowiki.org/Interfacial_tension